# python3: A sub-funtion of a class cannot correctly return its value. And the final value returned from a bigger program

Tags: python

#### The simplified codes:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = True

    def test(self):
        # if self.a is True:
        #     return 1
        self.sub_test()
        return 0

    def sub_test(self):
        if self.a is True:
            return 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A()
    print(a.test())
```

when I debugged the program, found the process had stepped into `return 1` but didn't correctly return the value 1, then jump into `return 0`. and the 0 is the final value.
However, the code below could corrrectly return the value 1.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = True

    def test(self):
        if self.a is True:
            return 1
        # self.sub_test()
        return 0

    def sub_test(self):
        if self.a is True:
            return 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A()
    print(a.test())
```

I looked up to some websites but did not get the answer. I think it maybe like the 'void' function of C so it rejects the return value, I don't know exactly. But in python, it has no error info and confuse me. Could somebody tell me why the mistake happended? Are there any measure to divide a long function of a class in python3 to several sub-funcs and make it works correctly?

Comment: Thank you and others to reply my question. Infact, The codes above was simplified from a  little long codes, and in this time, I think I had to use the `test` function as the "main" func. So the acceptable answer maybe seem naive but it indeedly works. I know it is not so perfect but it solve my problems. I'm new to python, I think I'll understand the problems more deeply in the future. Thank you again.

Comment: Oh, and the " short-circuit " works too. but actually the value I returned is a string type, and it also works. I  don't know the theory temporarily, but it looks so concise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the value returned from `sub_test`. Here is a naive way to fix your test function:

```py
def test(self):
    value = self.sub_test()
    if value == 1:
        return value
    return 0
```

You can then short-circuit it further:

```py
def test(self):
    return self.sub_test() or 0
```

This last approach works because your `sub_test` either return 1 or `None` (implicitly), depending on the value of `self.a`. If it returns a 1, then the expression `self.sub_test() or 0` becomes 1. If it returns a `None`, then the same expression becomes 0.

Comment: Thank you and others to reply my question. Infact, The codes above was simplified from a  little long codes, and in this time, I think I had to use the `test` function as the "main" func. So the acceptable answer maybe seem naive but it indeedly works. I know it is not so perfect but it solve my problems. I'm new to python, I think I'll understand the problems more deeply in the future. Thank you again.

Comment: Oh, and the " short-circuit " works too. but actually the value I returned is a string type, and it also works. I don't the theory temporarily, but it looks so concise!

Answer (score 1):

This is because `0` is being returned from the `sub_test` function, but not the `test` function.

Remember that when a function is called, it is not the same as copying and pasting its code into a new place; the `return` statement is only running within the sub-function.

What you might want to do is something like this:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = True

    def test(self):
        if self.sub_test():
            return 1
        return 0

    def sub_test(self):
        if self.a is True:
            return 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A()
    print(a.test())
```

Answer (score 1):

### It is not a mistake - but error in the code

#### What is the error, How to fix it :-

- Error is that you are just getting a value from a subfunction. the subfunction sub_test() is returning the value to class function test() not actually to the main program
- To fix it, change self.sub_test() to return self.sub_test()

#### fixed code :-

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = True
    
    def test(self):
        # here you have to return the value got from subfunction
        return self.sub_test()
    
    def sub_test(self):
        if self.a is True:
            return 1
        return 0 # to return 0 if not 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a mistake, the sub_test function actually returns 1 to the test function but after it returns 1 you are returning 0 back to function call. That's why it prints 0 instead of 1.

If you want to receive the 1 sent by sub_test you have to write the test function in the following manner

```
def test(self):
   return self.sub_test()
```